# Find last column with green cell fill

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, colors, date-range

I am fairly new to writing Macros. Every Friday I need to find the most recently completed operation in a process (last column in dataset), indicative by a green fill (5287936). Once found I need to pull the associated column label (text). There are multiple rows/process'

[image]

so I know I would need a for loop. I was thinking of approaching the problem with the range.find command, moving left from the furthest right column.

How should I go about this? Are there any resources that are recommended or advice to assist in this process.

Comment: Take a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a9814069%20searchformat%20%3d%20True%20score%3a2)

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that there are many thousands of different colors that could be called "green" in Excel.  Step one is to find out exactly the color you are interested in finding.  Select a cell that has the color you are looking for and run the following code to get the color number.  It will write the color number into the cell, replacing any content already there.

```
activecell.value=activecell.interior.Color
```

You will use that number to set the value of the "color" variable in the code below, which will find the last cell in row 1 with that color.

```
Sub find_last_green_column()
  
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' look on the active sheet
    'Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' look on a specific sheet
    
    Dim color As Long
    color = 65280      ' enter the result of the statement above here
    
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    
    Dim col As Integer
    
    For col = s.Columns.Count To 0 Step -1
       if col < 1 then 
           msgbox "Did not find color"
           exit sub
       end if  
       If s.Cells(row, col).Interior.color = color Then Exit For
    Next
    
    s.Activate
    s.Cells(row, col).Select
    
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to re-open? I'm not seeing in option to accept an answer.

Comment: Perhaps not.  oh well.  I would have liked the points, but I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: The above code does not work for me. I am receiving the following error: Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: I need to know what line causes the error so I can give you some guidance about how to use it in your worksheet.  That is the error you would get if the code does not find the color.   Be sure you have changed the code to look for the right color of green (as I explain in the answer).  I'll adjust the code to give a better message if the color is not found.